# Traffic light application: Implementing ActionListener in its own class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, jbutton

How would i go about modifying this program? The program was made to simulate a traffic light and the changing of the lights happens with a button click. I have made the program work just fine under the parameters of the assignment. The assignment needed 4 classes, a JFrame and 2 nested JPanels (one for trafficcontrol and one for the trafficlight panels). I However cannot seem to answer the last question of how to separate the innerclass for the action listener into its own separete entity, and still get the program to work.

### The Question

An inner class is used to facilitate communication between two classes when they 
have an intimate relationship. Make the inner class (ChangeListener) a regular class 
by taking it out from TrafficControlPanel and observe the complication involved in 
making them communicate and the intimacy of the two classes.

### Here is the program

```
Package traffic.light;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TrafficLight extends JFrame
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic Light");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(150, 230);
    frame.add(new TrafficControlPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}






package traffic.light;

import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class TrafficLightPanel extends JPanel 
{ 
 private int currentState = 0; 
 private final int NUM_LIGHTS = 3; // the number of lights 
 private final int X = 50, Y = 10, WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 130; //box size 
 private final int DIAMETER = 30; // light diameter 
 private final int X_OFFSET = 10, Y_OFFSET = 10; // offsets to position the lights in the box 
 private final int PANEL_WIDTH = 150, PANEL_HEIGHT = 230; // the size of a traffic control panel 

 //----------------------------------------------------------------- 
 // Creates the traffic light panel 
 //----------------------------------------------------------------- 
 public void TrafficLightPanel() 
 { 
 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 230)); 
 setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 } 

 public void paintComponent(Graphics page) 
 { 
 super.paintComponent(page); 
 int lightOn = currentState % NUM_LIGHTS; 
 setBackground(Color.white); 
 page.setColor(Color.lightGray); 
 page.fillRect(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT); 


 switch (lightOn)
         {
             case 0:
 page.setColor(Color.red);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),(Y+Y_OFFSET), 30, 30);
 page.setColor(Color.darkGray);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),60 , 30, 30);
 page.setColor(Color.darkGray);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),100, 30, 30);

                 break;
             case 1:
page.setColor(Color.darkGray);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),20, 30, 30);
 page.setColor(Color.yellow);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),60 , 30, 30);
 page.setColor(Color.darkGray);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),100, 30, 30);
                 break;
             case 2 :
 page.setColor(Color.darkGray);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),(Y+Y_OFFSET), 30, 30);
 page.setColor(Color.darkGray);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),60 , 30, 30);
 page.setColor(Color.green);
 page.fillOval((X+X_OFFSET),100, 30, 30);
                 break;

 }

 }


 public void change(int clickcount ) 
 { 
 currentState = clickcount ; 
 repaint();
 } 

}







package traffic.light;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class TrafficControlPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton push;
    private TrafficLightPanel LightPanel;
    int click = 0;

    public TrafficControlPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        LightPanel = new TrafficLightPanel();

        push = new JButton("Change Light");
        push.addActionListener(new TrafficControlPanel.ChangeListener());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 230));
        setBackground(Color.white);
        add(LightPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(push, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    }

      // this needs to be deleted and put into the ChangeListener class below
    private class ChangeListener implements ActionListener {
        int click = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            click++;
            LightPanel.change(click);
        }
    }
}






package traffic.light;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChangeListener implements ActionListener{

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          // what goes here?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please try to extract the essence of your question, don't post a mileful of code. What have you tried, what didn't work, etc?

Comment: im just clueless as to how im going to make a seperate class for the action listener of the button in my code. and then in turn send the variable for count to the lightcontrolpanel, and then onto the trafficcontrolpanel. the original question was to make the code, and a bonus question is to re-edit the code so that their is a separate class for the action listener. i just feel like its hard to explain this concept without first seeing the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is stated in the question:

> ...observe the complication involved in making them communicate and
>   the intimacy of the two classes.

The whole point of the task is to make you see that the communication gets much more complicated when the `ChangeListener` does not have access to inner variables.

To give you a few hints: You need to be able to call `LightPanel.Change` from within your `ChangeListener`. How can you send a reference to `LightPanel` to `ChangeListener`?

Comment: Having the ActionListener as an inner class of TrafficControlPanel gives me access to its class variable LightPanel. If I were to make the ActionListener its own regular class then I no longer have direct access to it and so you would no longer be able to just call LightPanel.change(click). This is where i am confused, i don't know how to do it as a beginner programmer and it's the reason I'm pleading for help.